# Why doesn't GlassFish admin port release on stop

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4

I am having a heck of a time with GlassFish 4 on my Mac OSX 10.9.1.

Never had this issue before. The first time I launch GlassFish, everything works fine.
Then I shut it down and that works.
Then when I start again, it says the Admin Port: 4848 is busy.

Apparently the shutdown is not releasing the admin port. (Although it does seem to be shutting down, because if I try to navigate to localhost:4848 from my browser it hangs)

When I do a lsof -i :4848 it shows me "*:appserv-http (LISTEN)" is listening. When I kill -9 that process that releases the port. But why does it need to be so difficult (especially since none of this can be handled by my IDE!)

Does anyone have a more automated idea how to stop the domain if asadmin stop-domain doesn't do the job?

```
victors-mbp:~ vgrazi$ cd programs/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/
victors-mbp:bin vgrazi$ ./asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start ........
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /Users/vgrazi/programs/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /Users/vgrazi/programs/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.

victors-mbp:bin vgrazi$ ./asadmin stop-domain
CLI306: Warning - The server located at /Users/vgrazi/programs/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1 is not running.
Command stop-domain executed successfully.

victors-mbp:bin vgrazi$ ./asadmin start-domain
There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.
Command start-domain failed.
victors-mbp:bin vgrazi$
```

Comment: Reinstalled GlassFish and it is back to normal. Let's see how long it lasts

Comment: I have never had this problem on 10.9.1. Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: 7u40. There is definitely something wrong here. I am narrowing it down to one of two possibilities: It either occurs 1. When the Mac hibernates for some amount of time while GlassFish is running or 2. If you deploy without first undeploying, even using auto-deploy. I have been forced to reinstall GlassFish around five times.